# Sort between multiple arguments in ArrayList c#

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and have gotten stuck on an assignment. The idea is to create an Arraylist with multiple arguments from another class. I am supposed to sort only one of the arguments in a list. If there is only one argument there is no problem´, but I have 5. What do I do?

```
ArrayList people = new ArrayList();
people.Add(new Student("Maria", "Svensson", "1989-06-14", "C#Programming", 7));
people.Add(new Student("Bahar", "Nasri", "1992-08-04", "C#Programming", 5));
people.Add(new Student("Kent", "Kaarik", "1967-12-12", "Software Development", 8));
people.Add(new Student("Ahmed", "Khatib", "1990-06-06", "C#Programming", 9));
people.Add(new Student("Lisa", "Lundin", "1984-01-22", "Software Development", 6));
people.Add(new Student("Peter", "Stark", "1987-08-24", "Software Development", 4));
people.Add(new Student("Christer", "Stefansson", "1987-04-02", "C#Programming", 10));

people.Sort();
foreach (Student item in people)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.firstN + " " + item.lastN + " " + item.birthD + " " + item.courseT + " " + item.gradeH);
}
```

I also get the "Failed to compare two elements in the array" This leads me to believe I need the ICompare command, but I am not sure how to use it. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!!

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but it appears you're storing a date as a string. That's a terrible idea. They're hard to manipulate programmatically. Instead, use [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Do you have to use an `ArrayList` ?, or could you use something like a `List<Student>` which would allow you to use LINQ to sort on any of the properties in your `Student` object

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+how+to+sort+a+list I'm sure this is a dupe of one of those!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an Arraylist consider a generic list List. Then use LINQ to sort your list.

```
List<Student> people = new List<Student>();
people.Add(new Student("Maria", "Svensson", "1989-06-14", "C#Programming", 7));
people.Add(new Student("Bahar", "Nasri", "1992-08-04", "C#Programming", 5));
people.Add(new Student("Kent", "Kaarik", "1967-12-12", "Software Development", 8));
people.Add(new Student("Ahmed", "Khatib", "1990-06-06", "C#Programming", 9));
people.Add(new Student("Lisa", "Lundin", "1984-01-22", "Software Development", 6));
people.Add(new Student("Peter", "Stark", "1987-08-24", "Software Development", 4));
people.Add(new Student("Christer", "Stefansson", "1987-04-02", "C#Programming", 10));

var orderedPeople = people.OrderBy(x => x.lastN);
foreach (Student item in orderedPeople)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.firstN + " " + item.lastN + " " + item.birthD + " " + item.courseT + " " + item.gradeH);
}
```

To sort by multiple columns, use ThenBy.

```
var orderedPeople = people.OrderBy(x => x.lastN).ThenBy(x => x.firstN);
```

Comment: NOTE: the example does not actually sort the list. This may or may not be fine for the OP. If all they really want is to have an ordered representation of the same data, this works well. Otherwise, a different approach (e.g. using List<T>.Sort()) is needed.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make a Comparer class and pass it to ArrayList.Sort():

```
    public class StudentComparer : IComparer<Student>, IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(Student x, Student y)
        {
            return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
        }


        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            return Compare(x as Student, y as Student);
        }
    }
```

And use it like this:

```
 list.Sort(new StudentComparer());
```

Comment: You do _not_ have to create a Comparer class, nor even use Comparer.Create(). Just use the `List<T>.Sort(Comparision<T>)` overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, sorry...I am assuming that the OP will take the important advice to stop using ArrayList. :)  Note that if they insist on sticking with ArrayList, it is still not necessary to write a whole new class just for this: `list.Sort(Comparer.Create((s1, s2) => s1.Name.CompareTo(s2.Name)))` is sufficient

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you should take the advice to switch to List instead of the old non-generic ArrayList. If you do that, then sorting the list is as simple as:

```
people.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.Name.CompareTo(s2.Name));
```

If you want to stick with ArrayList, it's almost as simple:

```
people.Sort(Comparer<Student>.Create((s1, s2) => s1.Name.CompareTo(s2.Name)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the advice. I ended up doing a generic list List and everything worked smoothly in the end. For the assignment I was supposed to do one with ArrayList, but in the end the generic one seemed way better. I am hoping that it will be ok!